# Hibernate -- Cascade.REMOVE from a mirror (inverse) class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have  class A and B as follows:

```
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer idd;
    public Integer getIdd() { return idd;   }
    public void setIdd(Integer idd) { this.idd = idd;   }

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="a")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.REMOVE)   
    //@Transient   
    private B b;
    public B getB() {  return b;  }
    public void setB(B b) {  this.b = b;  }

    private int someField;
    public int getSomeField() {  return someField;  }
    public void setSomeField(int someField) {  this.someField = someField;  }

    public A(int someField) { this.someField = someField;   }
    public A() {}

}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class B implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    public Integer getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id;  }

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = db.entityClasses.A.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idd", nullable = true)
    private A a;
    public A getA() {  return a;   }
    public void setA(A a) {  this.a = a;   } 

    private int ssomeField;
    public int getSsomeField() {  return ssomeField;    }
    public void setSsomeField(int someField) {  this.ssomeField = someField;  }

    public B() { }
    public B(A a, int ssomeField) {
    this.a = a;
    this.ssomeField = ssomeField;
    }
}
```

So with this, `B` is in a one-to-one association with `A`, and `B` is the owner. 
I'm looking to delete the corresponding row of `B` whenever i delete a row of `A`. 
For this, I'm cascading the deletion on `A`.

All else-- insertions to these tables, and deletion from `A` whenever `B` doesn't have a foreign key reference to it are working fine.

However, when I'm looking to delete a row, say row with `id=5` of `A` and `B` has a FK ref. to that row of `A`, i'm getting teh following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`PrjTEMP`.`b`, CONSTRAINT `FK4253917D0F` FOREIGN KEY (`idd`) REFERENCES `a` (`idd`))
```

What's wrong with this code???

Comment: Please post the jpa code where you delete the `A` entity as well. Are you using the JPA API or the Hibernate API?

Comment: @NándorElődFekete - delete() made it -- was deleting on a query. write this as an ans and i'll accept.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

was deleting with a query. delete() made it.